# How to properly pass username and password from reactjs to back end for authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a react app that has a onchange function on form which takes username and password. Then onSubmit I am passing the username and password through redux dispatch to server side nodejs.

In server side nodejs I am sending the credentials to aws cognito for authentication. The authentication works as intended.

What I want to know is, is passing the password like i am doing insecure? I have a feeling it is, but I am not sure how to exactly tackle the problem to tighten up the flow.

Suggestions?

Comment: Is your API call using https?

Comment: @Wainage, not during development (which i am in right now) but definitely for production it will be https

Comment: Then you'll be fine.

Comment: To me, the best way is to use an existing lib for exemple auth0 to hash the user credentials and pass a token with them, and check both of them.

Comment: @Wainage so even with https just sending the user and password to nodejs is fine? my impression was that passing variable like that might be a risk, but if not then great!

Comment: You can find a good exemple here ( medium are really awesome ) https://medium.appbase.io/securing-a-react-web-app-with-server-side-authentication-1b7c7dc55c16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of securing your communication channels is independent of what language or framework you are using. If the process of encrypting or decrypting a message required special steps specific to the application language, we would see far more problems in communication between systems that used different languages, less encryption in developer systems, and even more vulnerabilities in the ones that did apply it. Fortunately, the process is generally handled by servers and low-level utilities.

HTTPS is generally sufficient; it is the only encryption protecting most browser connections to pretty much everything. As long as the connection is using current protocols (TLS) with trusted certificates and neither of the communicating systems is compromised, current cryptography favors it. If attackers could reliably break key-based encryption, they could capture the credentials you use to *sign into* both your site and AWS, alter your settings and override whatever other security measures you had that did not require multi-factor authentication.

If it is good enough for your bank account, it will have to be good enough for your app - if only because anything else you need to communicate with is unlikely to support more obscure custom encryption, and anyone who can break through the outer layer should have no problem with any non-key layers.

I would focus on securing the end systems. In React, that especially means [preventing cross-site scripting](https://medium.com/javascript-security/avoiding-xss-in-react-is-still-hard-d2b5c7ad9412) so other sites cannot capture the session credentials. Factor in the challenges of locking down, tracking access to, and (where possible) encrypting data stored in the underlying systems, and the communication encryption is easy by comparison. As bato3 noted, you can reduce some of that burden by using OAuth sign-ins where possible - the fundamentals are the same, but the credentials are handled by proven systems.

Comment: Additionally: The rule is that if you use any APIs, you don't ask the user for their password, but he must authorize your application (eg .: OAuth2)

Comment: Right you are @bato3! Good practice that I will add.